# getting different version of java in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, command-line, jdk

I am getting different version of java when i run java -version and javac -version.
for java-version iam getting

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode


javac -version
javac 1.6.0_33`
```

My environment variable path in ~/.profile is: 

`export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/`

**Edit**

which java: `/usr/bin/java`

which javac `/usr/bin/javac`

Comment: Can you post the output of `which java` and `which javac`?

Comment: Also, how did you install java from Oracle, or is this a fresh installation with only OpenJDK?

Comment: check the edit.

Comment: Actually i had a previous java (1.6) and i installed jdk7 using apt-get commmand.

Comment: ok, so my guess is that your alternatives didn't get set properly. Just to verify that though, can you post the output of `dpkg -l | grep java -i` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From  your edit, it looks like you have two instances of the `openJDK` installed. If you want them to match, you have two options:

1. Uninstall the one you don't want. E.g. if you want open-jdk7 but not open-jdk6 do `sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk-6-*`
2. Update the alternatives for java using `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and pick the one you want. If you need to have both JDKs available, this is your best option as you can then just do that each time you need to switch

Comment: I choose option 2 as i need both version. But that too dosen't make the difference.

Comment: Did you do it for java or javac? or both?

Comment: Updating alternatives for javac works.

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora I was able to fix that error with this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java

There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-1.b14.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java
   2           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.101-2.6.6.1.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java
   3           /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/java
```

Then removing the old version of java:

```
sudo yum remove java-1.7*
```

Then I get the same version of java for each one:

Answer (score 0):

if ***java*** and ***javac*** are showing different versions, then you can easily set them to the correct or same versions

**step 1**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

output :

```
    Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1081      manual mode
```

this will show the following results, start(*) indicates the ***javac*** version that your system is using. You can change it by selecting your required version.

**step 2**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

output :

```
      Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

Now again you can select the version you want to run for ***java***.

This way you can ensure that java and javac are having the same versions.